# Filtering for HTTP methods in IPv6 packets using tcpdump

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, tcpdump

I am using "tcpdump" to capture traffic, and I want to filter by HTTP methods. When I have IPv4 packets, I am using: `tcpdump -s 0 -A 'tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2):4] = 0x47455420'` To filter for HTTP GET packets.

Unfortunately, the `tcp[]` filter doesn't work on IPv6 packets. According to the docs

> Arithmetic expression against transport layer headers, like `tcp[0]`, does not work against IPv6 packets.

So I am looking for another way to filter only HTTP methods for IPv6 traffic using tcpdump.

I have tried searching for a solution, but seems like they include a usage of grep which isn't suitable for my needs, since I want to output all the filtered traffic directly to a pcap file

Comment: The probable reason is that IPv6 can have *multiple* extension headers, variable in number, between the fixed header and the transport header. A check would require to check for the 0 extension case + the 1 extension case + the ... + the 9 extensions case making a very long bytecode result.

Comment: @A.B Got it. Is there a way to overcome this using tcpdump?

Answer (score 3):

### Limitations of `tcpdump` with IPv6 as of versions 4.99.x

For IPv4, to get the payload offset in the packet one can just more or less compute the payload offset by using [IPv4's IHL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_version_4#IHL) +  [TCP's data offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) to also account for IPv4 options and TCP options. This is simple enough to be included in *tcpdump* directly when it generates the BPF bytecode filter (some BPF documentation available for example [there](https://docs.kernel.org/networking/filter.html#bpf-engine-and-instruction-set)).

For IPv6, instead, there can be a variable (possibly between 0 and 9) number of extension header between the fixed header and the upper header. That would mean include code for possibly 10 cases (0, 1, 2, ... 9 extension headers) to find the payload offset in a packet, assuming there are no additional peculiarities for certain cases nor even attempting to have protection against malformed packets (which could lead to false positive match): I can only assume this was not implemented because of the complexity and the unwillingness to provide a flawed implementation ignoring such headers.

Even a simple test such as `ip6 and tcp dst port 80` doesn't consider extension headers as seen with the generated BPF code below:

```shell
$ tcpdump --version 
tcpdump version 4.99.3
libpcap version 1.10.3 (with TPACKET_V3)
OpenSSL 3.0.9 30 May 2023
$ tcpdump -y EN10MB -d ip6 and tcp dst port 80
(000) ldh      [12]
(001) jeq      #0x86dd          jt 2    jf 7
(002) ldb      [20]
(003) jeq      #0x6             jt 4    jf 7
(004) ldh      [56]
(005) jeq      #0x50            jt 6    jf 7
(006) ret      #262144
(007) ret      #0
```

so can miss traffic.

It appears as of tcpdump 4.99.x that the only place where adequate handling of IPv6 extension headers is in place is documented at the end of the man page:

> `ip6 proto` should chase header chain, but at this moment it does not. `ip6 protochain` is supplied for this behavior.

Indeed currently as of tcpdump 4.99.x `ip6 and tcp` is equivalent to `ip6 proto 6` (they produce the same bytecode):

```
$ tcpdump -y EN10MB -d ip6 and tcp
(000) ldh      [12]
(001) jeq      #0x86dd          jt 2    jf 8
(002) ldb      [20]
(003) jeq      #0x6             jt 7    jf 4
(004) jeq      #0x2c            jt 5    jf 8
(005) ldb      [54]
(006) jeq      #0x6             jt 7    jf 8
(007) ret      #262144
(008) ret      #0
```

while `ip6 protochain 6` does a way more thorough check and would be what should be expected in any test involving an upper-layer (final transport header) such as TCP:

```
$ tcpdump -y EN10MB -d ip6 protochain 6
(000) ldh      [12]
(001) jeq      #0x86dd          jt 2    jf 35
(002) ldb      [20]
(003) ldx      #0x28
(004) jeq      #0x6             jt 32   jf 5
(005) jeq      #0x3b            jt 32   jf 6
(006) jeq      #0x0             jt 10   jf 7
(007) jeq      #0x3c            jt 10   jf 8
(008) jeq      #0x2b            jt 10   jf 9
(009) jeq      #0x2c            jt 10   jf 19
(010) ldb      [x + 14]
(011) st       M[0]
(012) ldb      [x + 15]
(013) add      #1
(014) mul      #8
(015) add      x
(016) tax      
(017) ld       M[0]
(018) ja       4
(019) jeq      #0x33            jt 20   jf 32
(020) txa      
(021) ldb      [x + 14]
(022) st       M[0]
(023) txa      
(024) add      #1
(025) tax      
(026) ldb      [x + 14]
(027) add      #2
(028) mul      #4
(029) tax      
(030) ld       M[0]
(031) ja       4
(032) add      #0
(033) jeq      #0x6             jt 34   jf 35
(034) ret      #262144
(035) ret      #0
```

Above the 4 tests including `jt 10` and lines between `(10`) and `(018) ja       4` loop over 4 of the specific IPv6 extension headers to skip them, while `(19)` to `(31)` deal with IPSec AH. I wouldn't know how to generate elsewhere such code with the *tcpdump* language (rather than, say, direct *BPF* code). Using `ip6 protochain 6 and ip6 and tcp dst port 80` just starts over from scratch, or worse, rather than capitalizing on the just-obtained TCP header.

The same kind of problem is described in various network facilities and tools for Linux. Example: [`tc u32`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-u32.8#icmp_code) tells:

> `icmp_code` *VAL_MASK_8*
>
> Assume a next-header protocol of icmp or ipv6-icmp and match Type or Code field values. **This is dangerous, as the code assumes** minimal
> header size for IPv4 and **lack of extension headers for IPv6**.

All this doesn't even consider that specifically for HTTP, when the connection is reused, the next HTTP query might not even be on the start of a packet boundary, or also that such query embedded as data rather than query might match if such data appear at the start of the packet boundary.

### Test for the 0 extension-header case using `tcpdump` version 4.99.x

Here's the test with 0 extension headers, ie at the same level of what *tcpdump* currently does, with minimal verification done:

```
tcpdump -n -s 0 -A 'ip6[6] == 6 and ( ip6[4:2] - ((ip6[52] & 0xf0) >> 2) >= 4 ) and ip6[40 + ((ip6[52] & 0xf0) >> 2) :4] == 0x47455420'
```

which can be documented like this (still only for the 0 extension-header case, where the TCP header always starts at position 40):

- Next header is TCP

  ```
  ip6[6] == 6
  ```
- [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Fixed_header) payload length:

  ```
  ip6[4:2]
  ```
- [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) data offset (fixed IPv6's size of 40 + 12 = 52) (and adequate adjustment to get bytes)

  ```
  (ip6[52] & 0xf0) >> 2
  ```
- TCP payload length = IPv6 payload length - TCP data offset
- Test there are at least 4 bytes of TCP payload for at least the length of "GET "

  ```
  ip6[4:2] - ((ip6[52] & 0xf0) >> 2)  >= 4
  ```
- the 4 bytes string "GET " encoded in ASCII/UTF-8 can be represented with the 4-bytes value 0x47455420
- TCP payload offset is IPv6 fixed header length (40) + TCP data offset

  ```
  40 + ((ip6[52] & 0xf0) >> 2)
  ```
- test that the first 4-bytes word starting at IPv6 fixed header length (40) + data offset equals the value for the string "GET "

  ```
  ip6[40 + ((ip6[52] & 0xf0) >> 2) :4] = 0x47455420
  ```

### *nftables* with Linux kernel >= 5.15.54 + *tcpdump*

I propose a simple alternate Linux-only method using *nftables* and requiring a recent enough kernel (Linux kernel version [>= 5.15.54](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Makefile?h=linux-5.15.y&id=5445819e76a6fbcb9a848efd5569ea27e547f6ab) backported from [5.16](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/net/netfilter/nft_payload.c?h=linux-5.16.y&id=c46b38dc8743535e686b911d253a844f0bd50ead)) as well as [*nftables* >= 1.0.1](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?h=v1.0.1&id=b67abc51ba6f78be79f344dfda9c6d0753d79aea) to support the [`@ih` (inner header/payload) raw payload](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#RAW_PAYLOAD_EXPRESSION), rather than just `@th` (transport header) because *nftables* itself is way too limited to do arbitrary processing from `@th` in a useful manner.

The IPv6 datagram has already been parsed, including any IPv6 extension header, and @th as well as @in pointers  are already available to *nftables*: no further processing is needed to get all cases. I rely on *nftables* to fail a check if the packet is too short without having to compute the actual TCP payload size (contrary to *tcpdump* and BPF, *nftables* can't do subtractions, so there's no way to check the size properly).

The *nftables* example below attempts to mimic OP's precise example but can't always in all details without some adaptation. No direction nor port, captures incoming packets before NAT and outgoing packets after NAT (hence the hooks and priorities chosen). The selected packet is  finally [sent to the *nflog* facility](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#LOG_STATEMENT):

> In the second form of invocation (if *nflog_group* is specified), the
> Linux kernel will pass the packet to nfnetlink_log which will send the
> log through a netlink socket to the specified group. One userspace
> process may subscribe to the group to receive the logs [...]

```
table ip6 special_log
delete table ip6 special_log

table ip6 special_log {
        chain log_to_nflog {
                log group 4242
        }

        chain ih_filter {
                meta l4proto tcp @ih,0,32 0x47455420 counter jump log_to_nflog
        }

        chain c_ingress {
                type filter hook prerouting priority -150; policy accept;
                jump ih_filter
        }
        chain c_egress {
                type filter hook postrouting priority 150; policy accept;
                jump ih_filter
        }
}
```

On Linux, the *nflog* facility is available as a pseudo-interface to (*libpcap* and) *tcpdump*:

```shell
# tcpdump -D |grep nflog
12.nflog (Linux netfilter log (NFLOG) interface) [none]
```

The packets selected by *nftables* can thus be displayed with (reusing the same NFLOG group: 4242):

```
tcpdump -n -s 0 -A -i nflog:4242
```

Caveat: there's more latency than with a direct capture.

Note: correct handling by *nftables* of a case having an extension header was actually tested with UDP (rather than TCP) and fragmented packets (handled by the [Fragment header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Fragment))  using `socat` (in a separate network namespace to prevent `nf_defrag_ipv6` from kicking in) because it's way easier to generate a fragmented packet with UDP than with TCP and I didn't find an other method to have an extension header somewhere.